# Position of changed user in ordered grid

Tags: usability, user-expectation, human-interface-guideline

Here is a problem I'm facing now:

User selects a row in the table. Let's say Abraham Lincoln. The table is sorted by Name (alphabetical order). Now we open a dialog (SPA application) and change the name from Abraham to John. What will happen to this row in the table? Assume there are many rows and pages, so the change cannot fit on the current page anymore.

Where is the right place to show it? resort all rows and put a selector on this one? Leave the row as is, but then it is out of order.

What is the best practice?

Comment: Welcome to UXSE. Is the table sorted by alphabetical order?

Comment: yep, that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reordering the list an jump to a different page after closing the dialog would have an unexpected impact an could confuse the user.

Here is a way to deal with this problem:

If the new name is on e different page, stay on the same page (which would have one item less then before). Show a temporary message above the list like "the name was changed to 'John' **show this entry**" hide the message after a few seconds. This way it is clear to the user that the change was applied, the item is no longer visible and a shortcut to the page where the item will be found.

This way the order of the items will always be correct and the user is empowered to stay on the page an maybe change the next entry or go to the page with the just changed entry. Because it is a temporary message the user is not forced to interact with it an can go on with the next task without interruption.

Comment: Now that you said it, it reminded me of Gmail. Archive/delete - shows such message.